# Log errors in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am using VueJS and I've been bitten several times by the fact that it swallows all errors (undefined properties in templates as well as calling undefined errors in methods).

Is there a way to turn on all errors, or at least all errors happening in JS (and not in templates)?

Comment: Did you try using debug `Vue.config.debug = true`? With this Vue will print stacktrace errors/warnings.

Comment: Also ensure to be using the develpment version. From [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#Standalone): "don’t use the minified version during development. You will miss out all the nice warnings for common mistakes!"

Comment: I'll use the debug option then. And thanks @ragnar. That will create a complex setup though (differentiating dev and prod), too bad exceptions are just swallowed out of the box :/

Comment: `Vue.config.debug` doesn't exist in 2.0. I think you just want to NOT use the minified version and make sure you DON't set `Vue.config.silent` to `true`.

Comment: @BillCriswell thanks I've updated the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments:

- don't use the minified version in development

For VueJS 1.x:

- turn on the "debug" mode (this doesn't exist in Vue 2.0 anymore)

  ```
  config: {
      debug: true
  }
  ```

  or `Vue.config.debug = true`

Comment: How would you make sure that errors are properly logged to Sentry or Bugsnag in production (in case of bugs that have not been discovered while develping) ?

Comment: @conradk I honestly don't know, maybe you should ask that in a separate question to get answers